# MySQL UNION from one table with different parameters

Tags: mysql

Table contains information about parking zones. Each zone may have up to three rows - one for work days, one for Sunday and one for Saturday. Columns `is_workday` `is_saturday` `is_sunday` indicates days of the week. All fields can be set to `1` - it means the same parameters for whole week.

I am trying to get all zones information and set different aliases for different days of the week in one query.

```
SELECT t.zone_id, t.saturday_start_time, t.workday_start_time, t.sunday_start_time
FROM
(
(SELECT `zone_id`, `start_time` as `saturday_start_time` FROM `p2_zone_rates` WHERE `is_saturday`='1' ORDER BY `zone_id`)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `zone_id`, `start_time` as `workday_start_time` FROM `p2_zone_rates` WHERE `is_workday`='1' ORDER BY `zone_id`)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `zone_id`, `start_time` as `sunday_start_time` FROM `p2_zone_rates` WHERE `is_sunday`='1' ORDER BY `zone_id`)
) AS t
GROUP BY `zone_id`
```

Result of this query is error:
`#1054 - Unknown column 't.workday_start_time' in 'field list'`

Only first query from all creates alias but other queries use it instead of making new aliases.

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add 2 column in each union

```
    SELECT t.zone_id, t.saturday_start_time, t.workday_start_time, t.sunday_start_time
    FROM
    (
    (SELECT `zone_id`, `start_time` as `saturday_start_time` ,
    '' as workday_start_time, '' as sunday_start_time FROM `p2_zone_rates` WHERE `is_saturday`='1' ORDER BY `zone_id`)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT `zone_id`, `start_time` as `workday_start_time`,
    '' as workday_start_time, '' as sunday_start_time  FROM `p2_zone_rates` WHERE `is_workday`='1' ORDER BY `zone_id`)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT `zone_id`, `start_time` as `sunday_start_time`,
'' as workday_start_time, '' as sunday_start_time  FROM `p2_zone_rates` WHERE `is_sunday`='1' ORDER BY `zone_id`)
    ) AS t
    GROUP BY `zone_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a query like this

```
SELECT t.zone_id, (CASE WHEN `is_saturday`='1' THEN start_time ELSE NULL END) as `saturday_start_time` ,
(CASE WHEN `is_workday`='1' THEN start_time ELSE NULL END) as `workday_start_time`,
(CASE WHEN `is_sunday`='1' THEN start_time ELSE NULL END) as `sunday_start_time`;
```

You can add order by or group by as per reuirement